# How to I place data bounded by parenthesis on a single line?

Tags: sed, osx

I am trying to work with a large text file to place data that is bounded with parenthesis onto a single line. Currently it is broken across multiple lines...

What it looks like:

```
(123456
'abcdef'
'a1b2c3d4'
'1234567890'
0)
(789012
'zyxwv'
'987gha871'
'987654828'
0)
```

What I need to have it look like:

```
(123456 'abcdef' 'a1b2c3d4''1234567890' 0)
(789012 'zyxwv''987gha871''987654828' 0)
```

Trying to knock this out using a sed one-liner, but not having much luck. Any thoughts?

Thanks!!

Comment: `sed 'H;/(/h;/)/!d;x;s/\n/ /g'` works with your input sample... it's unclear whether the file may contain lines outside those parens (and if so what's the expected output)

Comment: If you are able to use `awk`, I have a simple solution for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s",$0,($0~/\)$/)? ORS:FS }' file
```

The output:

```
(123456 'abcdef' 'a1b2c3d4' '1234567890' 0)
(789012 'zyxwv' '987gha871' '987654828' 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

A **Perl** solution:

```
perl -nle 'if (/\(/../\)/) {push @a,$_;if (m/\)/) {print "@a";@a=()}}' file
```

This uses the [range](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) operator ("..") to capture in a any everything seen between (and including) an open parentheses and a closing one.  Once a closing parenthesis is sensed, the array contents are printed and the array cleared for the next cycle.